# Spring MVC URL Mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Hi I am creating a spring mvc app. The spring context seems to be mapping the controller methods to wrong urls.

I've following controllers:

HelloWorldController

```
package com.springapp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

ContactsController

```
package com.springapp.controller;

import com.springapp.form.Contact;
import com.springapp.service.ContactService;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public class ContactsController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listContacts(Model map) {

        map.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        map.addAttribute("contactList", contactService.listContacts());

        return "contact";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{contactId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showContact(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId) {

        contactService.getContact(contactId);
        return "redirect:/contacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact, BindingResult result) {

        contactService.addContact(contact);
        return "redirect:/contacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{contactId}/delete")
    public String deleteContact(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId) {

        contactService.removeContact(contactId);
        return "redirect:/contacts";
    }
}
```

However the spring context is mapping them as:

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/new] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/new.*] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/new/] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/addContact] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/addContact.*] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/addContact/] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/delete/{contactId}] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/delete/{contactId}.*] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/contacts/delete/{contactId}/] onto handler 'contactsController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
```

Where is it getting these `new` and `addContact` patterns? Also the mapping `/contacts` is missing.

Comment: The log in your question is very strange because it not matches mappings in your `ContactsController`. Are you sure you posted code and log from the same version?

Comment: @davioooh Incidentally I had a `addContact` mapping in the ContactsController earlier, which I later updated to just `add`. As you can see I've also changed the mapping for `deleteContact` but it is not taking effect.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to develop/run your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could depend on mappings you had in a old version of your application. 
Try to update the deployed version in Tomcat.

If you are using Eclipse to run/debug your project try to clean/compile your projet and than to deploy the new version in Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse and deploying on Glassfish.

Comment: Try to delete the deployed version and publish the new one.